# Enterprise Library Configuration Tool : How to stop showing application and database settings every time

Tags: enterprise-library, application-settings

I am using Enterprise Library 5.0 configuration tool from within VS2010.

Every time I open it, it keeps showing the following 2 settings even though I do not use them at all.

Application Settings

Database Settings

Its very annoying. How do I stop these 2 settings from showing up from within the configuration-tool unless I am actually using them.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database settings are there because there are database connection strings in machine.config. The way the .NET config system works, they show up when you enumerate sections.

AppSettings are there because just about every app does use appsettings, and so it was felt to be a convenience to include them. Note that this isn't an entlib section, it's the default .NET one.

There's no way to get them to stop showing up in the tool as written, you'd have to change the code of the config tool to change this behavior.